# Access dictionary values using list values as subsequent keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
keys = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']
dict = { prop1: { prop2: { prop3: True } } }
```

How do I get the value `True` out of the dict using the list?

Not having any success with

```
val = reduce((lambda a, b: dict[b]), keys)
```

update:

`keys` and `dict` can be arbitrarily long, but will always have matching properties/keys.

Comment: Are the dictionary keys variables or are those supposed to be strings?

Comment: see my update below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a loop:

```
>>> a = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'] 
>>> d = {'prop1': {'prop2': {'prop3': True}}}
>>> result = d
>>> for k in a: 
...     result = result[k] 
...
>>> result
True
```

Using a functional style:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(dict.get, a, d)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
As Op. rephrased his question, I made an update:

Actually you don't need for keys at all to get "True".
You can use a **recursive** function to do it nicely without knowing the keys.

```
d = { 'prop1': { 'prop2': { 'prop3': True } } }

def d_c(dc):
    if isinstance(list(dc.values())[0], dict):
        return d_c(list(dc.values())[0])
    return list(dc.values())[0]
```

**Result:**

```
True
```

Comment: @OrangePot it was not in the question